# There are infinitely many recursively enumerable subsets of the natural numbers which are not recursive

Tags: computability

How do I prove this claim? I understand that there are countably many recursive as well as recursively enumerable sets, and that the natural numbers have uncountably many subsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have one recursively enumerable but not recursive set, you can turn it into infinitely many.  Let the recursively enumerable but not recursive set be $A$.  Let $C=\{2n+1|n \in A\}$.  It is also recursively enumerable but not recursive.  To enumerate it, just enumerate $A$ and as each element comes out, double it and add one. If it were recursive, so would $A$ be.  Now define the family $B_i$ as $B_i=C \cup \{2j|0 \lt j \le i\}$

Comment: Or just $B_i=\{in\mid n\in A\}$.

Comment: @Ross Millkian And those are all different because C only consists of odd numbers and I add a few even ones to every one of the $B_i$s?

Comment: That is correct.  $B_i$ has the $i$ smallest even numbers in it plus all the odd ones from $C$

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  yes, that is even simpler.  Thanks